# Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am very new to SQL.

I have a table like this:

| ID | TeamID | UserID | ElementID | PhaseID | Effort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 6.74 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 8.25 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2.23 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 6.8 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 1.5 |

And I was told to get data like this

| ElementID | PhaseID1 | PhaseID5 | PhaseID6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NULL | 6.74 | 8.25 |
| 4 | 2.23 | 6.8 | 1.5 |

I understand I need to use PIVOT function. But can't understand it clearly.
It would be great help if somebody can explain it in above case.(or any alternatives if any)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

A [`PIVOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) used to rotate the data from one column into multiple columns.

For your example here is a STATIC Pivot meaning you hard code the columns that you want to rotate:

```
create table temp
(
  id int,
  teamid int,
  userid int,
  elementid int,
  phaseid int,
  effort decimal(10, 5)
)

insert into temp values (1,1,1,3,5,6.74)
insert into temp values (2,1,1,3,6,8.25)
insert into temp values (3,1,1,4,1,2.23)
insert into temp values (4,1,1,4,5,6.8)
insert into temp values (5,1,1,4,6,1.5)

select elementid
  , [1] as phaseid1
  , [5] as phaseid5
  , [6] as phaseid6
from
(
  select elementid, phaseid, effort
  from temp
) x
pivot
(
  max(effort)
  for phaseid in([1], [5], [6])
)p
```

Here is a [SQL Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/521090) with a working version.

This can also be done through a dynamic PIVOT where you create the list of columns dynamically and perform the PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.phaseid) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT elementid, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select elementid, phaseid, effort
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(effort)
                for phaseid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

The results for both:

```
ELEMENTID   PHASEID1    PHASEID5    PHASEID6
3           Null        6.74        8.25
4           2.23        6.8         1.5
```

Comment: Thanks got it. Only thing I need to hard code `PhaseID` before QUOTENAME. right?

Comment: in the QUOTENAME you have to identify which column you need to get the values from.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To make the STUFF solution work with strange column names (spaces, parentheses, etc.) I had to do `SELECT distinct '],['`, and also at the end of the statement `1, 2, '') + ']'`

Comment: @Web-E ,unfortunately yes. As a workaround you can write the query string in your application or play with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 8):

These are the very basic pivot example kindly go through that.

[SQL SERVER – PIVOT and UNPIVOT Table Examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

Example from above link for the product table:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
 PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
```

renders:

```
 PRODUCT FRED  KATE
 --------------------
 BEER     24    12
 MILK      3     1
 SODA   NULL     6
 VEG    NULL     5
```

Similar examples can be found in the blog post [Pivot tables in SQL Server. A simple sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

Comment: also note, if you pull extra numeric column from source table the pivot breaks the results into many rows.

Example
`SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA

FROM (SELECT rand() as x, CUST, PRODUCT, QTY FROM Product) up
PIVOT (
 SUM(x) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA)
) AS pvt

ORDER BY CUST
GO`

In order for this to work, you have to remove `qty` column from source

Answer (score 8):

Ive something to add here which no one mentioned.

The `pivot` function works great when the source has 3 columns: One for the `aggregate`, one to spread as columns with `for`, and one as a pivot for `row` distribution. In the product example it's `QTY, CUST, PRODUCT`.

However, if you have more columns in the source it will break the results into multiple rows instead of one row per pivot based on unique values per additional column (as `Group By` would do in a simple query).

See this example, ive added a timestamp column to the source table:

[image]

Now see its impact:

```
SELECT CUST, MILK

FROM Product
-- FROM (SELECT CUST, Product, QTY FROM PRODUCT) p
PIVOT (
    SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (MILK)
) AS pvt

ORDER BY CUST
```

[image]

---

In order to fix this, you can either pull a subquery as a source as everyone has done above - with only 3 columns (this is not always going to work for your scenario, imagine if you need to put a `where` condition for the timestamp).

Second solution is to use a `group by` and do a sum of the pivoted column values again.

```
SELECT 
CUST, 
sum(MILK) t_MILK

FROM Product
PIVOT (
    SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (MILK)
) AS pvt

GROUP BY CUST
ORDER BY CUST

GO
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A pivot is used to convert one of the columns in your data set from rows into columns (this is typically referred to as the *spreading column*). In the example you have given, this means converting the `PhaseID` rows into a set of columns, where there is one column for each distinct value that `PhaseID` can contain - 1, 5 and 6 in this case.

These pivoted values are *grouped* via the `ElementID` column in the example that you have given.

Typically you also then need to provide some form of *aggregation* that gives you the values referenced by the intersection of the *spreading value* (`PhaseID`) and the *grouping value* (`ElementID`). Although in the example given the *aggregation* that will be used is unclear, but involves the `Effort` column.

Once this pivoting is done, the *grouping* and *spreading columns* are used to find an *aggregation value*. Or in your case, `ElementID` and `PhaseIDX` lookup `Effort`.

Using the *grouping, spreading, aggregation* terminology you will typically see example syntax for a pivot as:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
    SELECT <grouping column>
        , <spreading column>
        , <aggregation column>
    FROM <source table>
)
SELECT <grouping column>, <distinct spreading values>
FROM PivotData
    PIVOT (<aggregation function>(<aggregation column>)
        FOR <spreading column> IN <distinct spreading values>));
```

[This](http://codebuildrepeat.blogspot.com/2019/04/pivot-and-unpivot-in-t-sql.html) gives a graphical explanation of how the *grouping, spreading and aggregation* columns convert from the source to pivoted tables if that helps further.

```
  Group Spread Agg
  Cars  2020   50
  Cars  2021   60
  Cars  2022   40
  Bikes 2020   100

            Spreading
  Group     2020       2021        2022   <-- Spread
  Cars      50           60          40   <-- Agg
  Bikes     100
```

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation that helped my understand how PIVOT works rather than blindly copying code and trying for force my own data into it. The only thing that I needed to add (to prevent an error message) was to name the PIVOT clause by adding 'AS PivotTable' (or similar) to the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
    SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    ...
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>
FROM
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)
    AS <alias for the source query>
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
<optional ORDER BY clause>;

USE AdventureWorks2008R2 ;
GO
SELECT DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost 
FROM Production.Product
GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;

    DaysToManufacture          AverageCost
0                          5.0885
1                          223.88
2                          359.1082
4                          949.4105

    -- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;




Here is the result set.
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days    0         1         2           3       4       
AverageCost                       5.0885    223.88    359.1082    NULL    949.4105
```

Comment: why is the `<SELECT query that produces the data>` not just  table?

Answer (score 3):

To set Compatibility error

use this before using pivot function

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

[FOR XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537490/is-or-is-not-for-xml-supported-in-sql-azure) might not work on Microsoft Azure Synapse Serve. A possible alternative, following @Taryn dynamic generated cols approach, same results is obtained by using [STRING_AGG](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5542/using-for-xml-path-and-stringagg-to-denormalize-sql-server-data/).

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.phaseid),', ')
/*OPTIONAL: within group (order by cast(t1.[FLOW_SP_SLPM] as INT) asc)*/
FROM (SELECT phaseid FROM temp
GROUP BY phaseid) c

set @query = 'SELECT elementid,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select elementid,
                phaseid,
                effort
                from temp
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                max(effort)
                for phaseid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```