# Bring similar multiple rows of a column into single row using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to 
Table name: Master_Vendors

```
Vendor_ID   Subvendor_id Subvendor_type Name   City State
1           abc           1              Johnny  York   MN
1           xyz           2              Meera   Birmingham NY
1           gef           3              Gaurav  Cochin NY
2           aaa           1              Laila   Lima   MA
2           bbb           2              Zebo    Reno   SC
2           ccc           3              Gina    Pitts  NY
```

I want one row per Vendor_ID and i cannot use any aggregations

```
Vendor_ID  Subvendor_id_1 Name_1 City_1 State_1 Subvendor_id_2 Name_2  City_2     State_2 
1           abc           Johnny  York   NY      xyz           Meera   Birmingham  NY
2           aaa           Laila    Lima  MA      bbb           Zebo    Reno        SC
```

since i cannot do aggregations i cannot use PIVOT; i have never used CTE's before can  we acheive this using CTE?

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow! while we would love to help, we aren't here to do your work for. Please provide some examples of what you have tried.

Comment: You are trying to `pivot` your results.  Lots of examples on SO for this already.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Try to solve the problem and come back to us if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql

Comment: are you limited to only 3 subvendors per vendor? If not, then I would seriously consider re-visiting your actual requirement..

Comment: It actually has 4 subvendors per vendor, it can range between 1-4 but not more than 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put in all the fields just enough so you can see the technique. Note this only works when you know in advance how many subvendors you want to show in the query:

```
select a.vendor_id , a.subvendor_id as Subvendor_id 1, a. Name as name_1, b.subvendor_id as Subvendor_id 2, b. Name as name_1, c.subvendor_id as Subvendor_id 3, a. Name as name_3
From Master_Vendors a
left join Master_Vendors b on a.vendor_id = b.vendor_id and  b.subvendor_type = 2
left join Master_Vendors c on a.vendor_id = c.vendor_id  and  c.subvendor_type = 3
where a.subvendor_type = 1
```

If every record would have all three subvendors then you can use inner joins.

Comment: This is actually working, Thank you so much! I actually kept the left join as is because the subvendors per vendor can range between 1 and 4

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the PIVOT function but only if you use MS SQL Server 2008 or Higher, Or simply use the CASE WHEN Statement as below:

```
SELECT Vendor_ID    as 'Vendor_ID ',
       case when Location_ID =1 then Location_ID END as 'Location_ID_1 ' 
      ,case when City ='York' OR City ='Lima' then City END as 'City_1 ' 
      ,case when [State]='MN'  OR [State]='NA' then [State] END as 'State_1' 
      ,case when Location_ID =2 then Location_ID END as 'Location_ID_2 ' 
      ,case when City ='Birmingham' OR City ='Reno'  then City END as 'City_2 ' 
      ,case when [State]='NY' OR [State]='SC' then [State] END as 'State_2 ' 
      ,case when Location_ID =3 then Location_ID END as 'Location_ID_3 ' 
      ,case when City ='Cochin' then City END as 'City_3  ' 
      ,case when [State]='NY'  then [State] END as 'State_3 ' 
FROM Master_Vendors
```

Comment: I am using Sqlserver2008;I changed my question, please take a look at it; the case statement doesnt result in a single row.