# sql from row to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help me out with the following issue. want to convert row data into the columns based on value of `"PeriodNum"` column max column will up to period8... there are multiple teachers in the table...below is just sample of 2 teachers.

Sample of data:

```
id      teachername course_name               periodnum   courseid
------------------------------------------------------------------
14088   Smith, John 1; Physical Education 9  GYM  ABCD  1   10064
14088   Smith, John 2; Physical Education 9  GYM  ABCD  2   10064
14088   Smith, John 3; Physical Education 11  GYM  BD   3   10065
14088   Smith, John 5; Physical Education 11  GYM  AC   5   10065
14088   Smith, John 6; Physical Education 11  GYM  ABCD 6   10065
14088   Smith, John 7; Health 9  P373  ABCD 7   10059
14088   Smith, John 8; Physical Education 11  GYM  AC   8   10065
14088   Smith, John 8; Health 10  GYM  BD   8   10066
15411   Yong, Jerry 1; Science 6  ABCD  1   10078
15411   Yong, Jerry 2; Science 9  ABCD  2   10078
15411   Yong, Jerry 3; Science 11    BD 3   10078
15411   Yong, Jerry 5; Science 11   AC  5   10078
15411   Yong, Jerry 6; Science 11  ABCD 6   10078
15411   Yong, Jerry 7; Maths  P373  ABCD    7   10080
15411   Yong, Jerry 8; Biology 11 AC    8   10041
```

I want to have desired result to look like following:

```
id  teachername Period1 Period2 Period3 Period4 Period5 Period6 Period7 Period8
14088   Smith, John 1; Physical Education 9  GYM  ABCD  2; Physical Education 9  GYM  ABCD  3; Physical Education 11  GYM  BD   NULL    5; Physical Education 11  GYM  AC   6; Physical Education 11  GYM  ABCD 7; Health 9  P373  ABCD 8; Physical Education 11  GYM  AC + 8; Health 10  GYM  BD
15411   Yong, Jerry 1; Science 6  ABCD  2; Science 9  ABCD  3; Science 11    BD     5; Science 11   AC  6; Science 11  ABCD 7; Maths  P373  ABCD    8; Biology 11 AC
```

thanks...so much.

I've tried following query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    t.[id],
    t.[teachername]
        ,t1.course_name AS period1,t2.course_name AS period2,t3.course_name AS period3, t4.course_name AS period4, t5.course_name AS period5, t6.course_name AS period6,
         t7.course_name AS period7,t8.course_name AS period8 -- into ccs_test
    FROM @teacher t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t1 ON t.[id]=t1.[id] AND t1.ColumnNumber=1 and  t.periodnum=1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t2 ON t.[id]=t2.[id] AND t2.ColumnNumber=2 and t.periodnum=2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t3 ON t.[id]=t3.[id] AND t3.ColumnNumber=3 and t.periodnum=3
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t4 ON t.[id]=t4.[id] AND t4.ColumnNumber=4 and t.periodnum=4
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t5 ON t.[id]=t5.[id] AND t5.ColumnNumber=5 and t.periodnum=5
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t6 ON t.[id]=t6.[id] AND t6.ColumnNumber=6 and t.periodnum=6
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t7 ON t.[id]=t7.[id] AND t7.ColumnNumber=7 and t.periodnum=7
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyGrouped t8 ON t.[id]=t8.[id] AND t7.ColumnNumber=8 and t.periodnum=8
```

Regards,
HT

Comment: Please format your code so it is actually readable, and provide queries you've already tried.

Comment: What database are you using since there are functions on some that do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)

Comment: Thanks @AHiggins for pointing me to the thread...that solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought the data into a table in SQL Server and was able to pivot to the results you were looking for.

```
SELECT ID
, TeacherName
,[1] as Period1
,[2] as Period2
,[3] as Period3
,[4] as Period4
,[5] as Period5
,[6] as Period6
,[7] as Period7
,[8] as Period8
FROM 
(SELECT ID, TeacherName, peridonum, course_name
FROM teacher) src
PIVOT
(MAX(course_name) FOR peridonum in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinnie  my issue is resolved now... thanks so much again.