# Query which converts rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have something like

```
ZoneNumber  AverageSpeed
      1             20
      2             30
      3             50
      4             60
      5             70
```

And I want to have a view like

```
AverageSpeed 1  AverageSpeed 2  AverageSpeed 3  AverageSpeed 4  AverageSpeed 5
         20                30              50              60              70
```

Does anyone have any ideas what my query need to be written like?

Comment: With sql you are using? if mssql, try PIVOT.

Comment: Which database system are you using?  MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle, something else?

What language is the target of your query?

Do you want an array of objects returned, an array of tuples, and array of arrays or just a giant string, or do you really want an sql row back, with just the average speeds, 20, 30, 50, 60, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Pivot rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.

[Basic example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT year(invoiceDate) as [year], left(datename(month,invoicedate),3) as [month], InvoiceAmount as Amount 
    FROM Invoice
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot
```