# Multiple COUNT(DISTINCT) from CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, count, common-table-expression

This is for SQL Server 2012: a subset of the data in my CTE looks like this:

```
Employee | OrderID | OrderType
---------+---------+----------
Kala     | 321111  | 953
Paul     | 321222  | 1026
Don      | 321333  | 1026
Don      | 321333  | 953
Kala     | 321444  | 953
```

I'd like the following result:

```
Employee | 953_Order_Count | 1026_Order_Count
---------+-----------------+-----------------
Kala     |        2        |    0
Don      |        1        |    1
Paul     |        0        |    1
```

To validate that I want is possible in my mind, when I run:

```
SELECT 
    Employee,
    OrderType,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS 'Count'
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY 
    employee, ordertype
```

The following result is returned:

```
Employee | OrderType | Count
---------+-----------+------
Kala     | 953       | 1
Paul     | 1026      | 1
Don      | 1026      | 1
Don      | 953       | 1
```

Close, but not close enough.  So I run:

```
SELECT 
    Employee,
    COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS 'Total_Orders',
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN OrderType = 1026 THEN OrderID END)) AS '1026_Order_Count',
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN OrderType = 953 THEN OrderID END)) AS '953_Order_Count'
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY 
    Employee
```

The result is an accurate first "count," but the rest return 0.  If this were not a CTE, I'd use a recursive statement.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To clarify a bit, the OrderID may have more than OrderType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN OrderType = 953  THEN 1 END) AS [953_Order_Count],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN OrderType = 1026 THEN 1 END) AS [1026_Order_Count]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
    Employee;
```

[image]

### Demo

The 953 count, for example, works above by counting 1 when the order type is 953 and `NULL` (the implicit `ELSE` value) when the order type is not 953.  `COUNT` ignores `NULL` by default, so it only counts the 953 orders.

Comment: Thanks, @tim-biegeleisen.  This wasn't working because I had a typo in my case statement - even after staring at it for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer looks fine.  You could also use a PIVOT:

```
; with cte (Employee, OrderID, OrderType)
as
(
    select 'Kala', 321111, 953
union select 'Paul', 321222, 1026
union select 'Don', 321333, 1026
union select 'Don', 321333, 953
union select 'Kala', 321444, 953
)
select Employee, [953] as [953_Order_Count],[1026] as [1026_Order_Count]
from 
    (
        select Employee, OrderType from cte ) as sourceData
pivot
(
    count(OrderType)
    for OrderType
    in ([953],[1026])
) as myPivot
```

If you want to have dynamic columns based on the set of available values in the `OrderType` column, you can build the query dynamically.  See @Taryn's answer to [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql) for an example.

Comment: This also works - and will be my foray into pivots.  Thank you!