# How to write vertical columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a vertical table horizontally with sql

I want to make the following table like the example in the second picture

example

[image]

ı want to write

[image]

Comment: search for `PIVOT`

Comment: Please Google for "SQL pivot query"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @DynamicColumn nvarchar(max),
        @MaxDynamicColumn nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+QUOTENAME(CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)))
FROM #Temp  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 
SELECT @DynamicColumn

SET @Sql='SELECT  '+ @DynamicColumn+'
            FROM
            (
            SELECT *
            FROM #Temp   o
            )AS src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX(Col2) FOR [Col1] IN ('+@DynamicColumn+')
            ) AS Pvt
             '
EXEC (@Sql)
PRINT @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if understand your query i think this query can help you to get excepted result :

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (colName varchar(250), colOther varchar(250))

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT 'Desen', '2908A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Desen', '2908A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Desen', '2908A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Desen', '2908A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Ebat', '125x200 R' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Ebat', '125x200 R' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Ebat', '125x200 R' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Ebat', '125x200 R' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ZeminRengi', 'KEMIK' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ZeminRengi', 'KEMIK' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ZeminRengi', 'KEMIK' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ZeminRengi', 'KEMIK' 


select Desen,Ebat,ZeminRengi
from #TEMP
PIVOT (
    MAX(colOther)
    FOR colName IN (Desen,Ebat,ZeminRengi)) AS Pvt

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

See different link and google : 
[Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)
[Google- search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=PIVOT%20SQL%20SERVER)