# Like to transfer rows to columns [advanced]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with many rows like:

```
category1 | keyword1 | type keyword1
category1 | keyword2 | type keyword1
category2 | keyword3 | type keyword2
category2 | keyword4 | type keyword1
category2 | keyword5 | type keyword2
category3 | keyword6 | type keyword3
category4 | keyword7 | type keyword2
category4 | keyword8 | type keyword3
category4 | keyword9 | type keyword1
category4 | keyword1 | type keyword1
```

I'd like to transform this to:

```
category1 | keyword1 | type keyword1 | keyword2 | type keyword1
category2 | keyword3 | type keyword2 | keyword4 | type keyword1 | keyword5 | type keyword2
category3 | keyword6 | type keyword3
category4 | keyword7 | type keyword2 | keyword8 | type keyword3 | keyword9 | type keyword1 | keyword1 | type keyword1
```

Problem is:

- I have an inconsistent number of rows per category

Comment: And how do you like to approach this problem? VBA or Formula? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I tried to load it into a database (SQL), but failed writing a query to do this..
And in excel i tried all kind of standard functions, but found nothing that worked.

Comment: You'd probably need to use `PIVOT` in sql ([something a bit like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)), except in that case, SQL would put your keywords in the same column (all keyword1 in one column, keyword2 in another column, etc)

Comment: FYI power query in Excel 2010 and later versions can handle this job too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Through worksheet functions:***

[image]

Formula in `E2` (and drag down):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11),0))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula that needs be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Formula in `F2` (and drag right and down):

```
=IFERROR(IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0,INDEX($B$1:$B$11,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11=$E2,ROW($A$2:$A$11),""),ROUND(COLUMN(A1)/2,0))),INDEX($C$1:$C$11,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11=$E2,ROW($A$2:$A$11),""),ROUND(COLUMN(A1)/2,0)))),"")
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula that needs be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Also, I'm sure there will be a possibility to do this through `PowerQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option and in non-array formula

Assume "Input table" housed in `A1:C11` with header, and "Output table" housed in `E1:N5` with header (something like JvdV's table layout)

Then, in `E2`, copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11),0),0)),"")
```

In `F2`, copied across to `N2` and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$11)/1%+{2,3}/($A$2:$A$11=$E2),COLUMN(A1)),"R0C00"),0),"")
```

Comment: Both formulas are actually still array-formulas, just not entered as such. The second one is also volatile. Either way, + for the option to choose :)