# Dynamic select statement to convert recordset into a readable format

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, pivot, unpivot

I am stumped on an output query.  I feel unpivot will get me there but I can't seem to get the syntax correct and could use some help.  Basically, a single record set contains two columns and one column is actually the column name while the other column is the column value.  Ideally I would like the output to label column 2 as column 1's result for each possible unique value.  Below is a simplified sample but the final solution could contain an infinite number of attributes per pc.

```
create table #t (pc int, attribute varchar(100), result varchar(100) )
go
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1,'OS','LINUX'),(1,'VERSION','10.4'),(2,'OS','WINDOWS'),(2,'VERSION','10.1903'),(3,'OS','LINUX'),(3,'VERSION','11.0'),(4,'OS','WINDOWS'),(4,'VERSION','10.1909'),(5,'OS','WINDOWS'),(5,'VERSION','10.1909'),(6,'OS','LINUX'),(6,'VERSION','10.4')
go
select * from #t
```

Result Set:

```
id pc  attribute   result
1   OS          LINUX
1   VERSION     10.4
2   OS          WINDOWS>
2   VERSION     10.1903
3   OS          LINUX
3   VERSION     11.0
4   OS          WINDOWS
4   VERSION     10.1909
5   OS          WINDOWS
5   VERSION     10.1909
6   OS          LINUX
6   VERSION     10.4
```

Desired Output:

```
pc OS          VERSION
1   LINUX       10.4
2   WINDOWS     10.1903
3   LINUX       11.0
4   WINDOWS     10.1909
5   WINDOWS     10.1909
6   LINUX       10.4
```

Any tips/advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers mate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding PIVOT function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql)

Comment: That did the trick.  It was the @cols string that I was using incorrectly.  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be obtained from a simple PIVOT. Refer to the below added code sample. I hope you find the answer here.

```
SELECT 
   PIVOTED.* 
FROM 
 (

    select * 
    from  #t

   ) AS P
PIVOT
(

   MIN(P.result)

   FOR P.attribute in ([OS],[Version])

 ) AS PIVOTED
```

Output from the PIVOT Query:
[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bHTc.png)

Comment: I will add the dynamic PIVOT for this to obtained infinite number of attributes per pc. So, that you will be able to use it for n number of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic PIVOT Solution for the answer as you can add any number of attributes and obtained the  result you need.

```
DECLARE @SQL  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @cols_ AS  VARCHAR(MAX) 

--Making the column list dynamically 
SELECT @cols_   = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(  C.attribute) 
               FROM  #t  C                 
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')              

--preparing PIVOT query dynamically. 

SET @SQL = ' SELECT
             pivoted.* 
      
            FROM 
              (
               SELECT * 
               FROM   #t 
              ) AS cp
              PIVOT
               (
                  MIN([CP].[result]) 
                  FOR  [CP].[attribute] IN (' + @cols_ + ')
              ) AS pivoted;  ' ;
```

PRINT( @SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)

I added below lines to the table #t  to test the result.
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1,'SNO','0012')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2,'SNO','0013')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (3,'SNO','0014')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (4,'SNO','0015')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (5,'SNO','0016')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (6,'SNO','0017')

Below find the result for the dynamic pivot.
[Dynamic PIVOT result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwgc0.png)